# Android: list jumps to other post when scrolling because ImageView height is wrap_content

Tags: java, android, scroll, imageview, android-glide

I have a list which contains posts that each contain one image. The ImageView width is set to match_parent, so it's always the same. Thee ImageView height is set to wrap_content, so the image height is not always the same. The last thing is what causes a problem with scrolling, because I'm also using Glide. The system doesn't know how far it has to scroll until Glide loads the picture, gets the dimensions of it and then resizes the ImageView. When the picture is done loading and the ImageView height is set, the list "jumps" and the screen shows another post. This is solved when wrap_content is replaced by a fixed value, but this is not what I want, because in that case there's a lot of empty space around the picture for some images.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Edit: the solution works, but it was still not what we wanted to achieve. We ended up changing the JSON. It now shows a ratio as well, with which the size of the ImageView can be calculated before the picture is loaded. This way the ImageView has a fixed size anyway, but it's an individual fixed size.

Comment: Use fixed size, but set an image placeholder to be shown, before photo is loaded to get rid of empty space

Comment: Read what I said. I don't want to use a fixed size, because in that case there's a lot of empty space around the picture for some images (they don't all have the same ratio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `Glide.with.pauseRequests`:

> if you call Glide.with(fragment/activity).pauseRequests(), new
>   requests will not run until you make a corresponding resumeRequests()
>   call. Those changes let you add an OnScrollListener and pause/resume
>   requests depending on the scroll state.

Comment: Yay, thank you! This works perfectly:

`if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Glide.with(getContext()).resumeRequests();
                } else {
                    Glide.with(getContext()).pauseRequests();
                }`